# Download a PDF file and capture the filename

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a URL to a PDF resource but it is not identified by it's filename. The request looks like this:

```
GET /api/docs/12345
Accept: application/pdf
```

And the response is:

```
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.pdf"
```

When I invoke the api with Postman, it will prompt to save the file with a default filename of "response". So the file get's save as "response.pdf". I need to do this programmatically using a RestTemplate client. How can I capture the response, so I can extract the filename (like in the above response it is sample.pdf) and I can save the file accordingly and not a generic filename such as "response.pdf"

Answer (score 6):

Using spring boot you can get the file name with:

```
response.getHeaders().getContentDisposition().getFilename()
```

in the following context:

```
    public void retrieveFile() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);


    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class, "1");

    if(response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK))
    {
        byte[] scenarioBytesFile = response.getBody();
        String fileName = response.getHeaders().getContentDisposition().getFilename();

        // Do Someting with your file and name 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer SOME_BEARER_TOKEN"); //if requires some token
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF));

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    try {
        ResponseEntity<Resource> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://SOME_API.COM/api/docs/12345",
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, Resource.class);


        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            String disposition =  response.getHeaders().get("Content-Disposition").get(0);
            String fileName = disposition.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"?([^\"]+)\"?.*$", "$1");//get the filename from the Content-Disposition header
            fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName, String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

            //save to examine file
            File targetFile = new File("c:/temp/" + fileName);
            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(response.getBody().getInputStream(), targetFile);
        }
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```